# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o57.showString. : org.apache.spark.SparkException:

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark

I am working with pyspark connected to an AWS instance (r5d.xlarge 4 vCPUs 32 GiB) running a data base 25 GB, when I run some tables I got the error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o57.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I  tried to find out the error for myself but unfortunately the is not much information regarding this issue.

code

---

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').\
     config('spark.jars.packages', 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.44').\
     appName('test').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('jdbc').\
        option('url', 'jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3306').\
        option('driver', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').\
        option('user', 'xxxxxxxxxxx').\
        option('password', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').\
        option('dbtable', 'dbname.tablename').\
        load()

  df.printSchema()
```

---

here I get the printSchema but then:

---

```
df_1 = df.select(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 
                  'col4', 'col5', 'col6']).show()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o57.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task            
  in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 
  0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC 
  overhead limit exceeded
```

---

Anybody an idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: show() doesn't return an object that could be assigned. What values have you set for `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.driver.memory`?

Comment: I did not set any of them, but I will try adding to the code the following: 

    _conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")_
    _conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")_
    _conf.set("spark.cores.max", "2")_

Do you have any recommendation for numbers I should use?

Comment: unfortunately does not work with the configuration above, the notebook keep running until the server is disconnected.... any suggestions ?

Comment: Is the error message still the same? Check the envionment tab of the spark ui if the values are assigned correctly.

Comment: check your partitions ```df.rdd.getNumPartitions()``` ... since you are reading from JDBC you will only get 1 partition hence you need to create a row boundary so the data can be split and distributed ... right now you are trying to process 25GB on a single machine with no parallelism hence OOM error

Comment: @cronoik I tried with diversity possibilities and unfortunately I got the following error: 

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 2015421 ms
Driver stacktrace....

Comment: @thePurplePython do you have an code example? I am trying to find in internet but it is not really easy ... sorry but i am pretty new in this programming world and sometimes i get pretty stuck .... thanks for the advice!

Comment: could you confirm the # of partitions by running ```df.rdd.getNumPartitions()```

Comment: @thePurplepython yes the number is 1 when I run `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`

Comment: ok ... please see answer/references below ... it should help you get started with parallelizing serial jdbc reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method to parallelize serial JDBC reads across multiple `spark workers` ... you can use this as a guide to customize it to your source data ... basically the main prerequisite is to have some kind of unique key to split on.

Please refer to this documentation specifically parameters `partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Some code examples:

```py
# find min and max for column used to split on
from pyspark.sql.functions import min, max

minDF = df.select(min("id")).first()[0] # replace 'id' with your key col
maxDF = df.select(max("id")).first()[0] # replace 'id' with your key col
numSplits = 125 # you will need to tailor this value to your dataset ... you mentioned your source as 25GB so try 25000 MB / 200 MB = 125 partitions

print("df min: {}\df max: {}".format(minDF, maxDF))

# your code => add a few more parameters
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').\
        option('url', 'jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3306').\
        option('driver', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').\
        option('user', 'xxxxxxxxxxx').\
        option('password', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').\
        option('dbtable', 'dbname.tablename').\
        option('partitionColumn', 'id').\ # col to split on
        option('lowerBound', minDF).\ # min value
        option('upperBound', maxDF).\ # max value
        option('numPartitions', numSplits).\ # num of splits (partitions) spark will distribute across executor workers
        load()

print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

Another example connection string => if you are using spark 2.4 / refer to this doc it uses some cleaner code

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#manage-parallelism

```py
sourceDF = spark.read.jdbc(
  url=jdbcUrl, 
  table="dbname.tablename",
  column='"id"',
  lowerBound=minDF,
  upperBound=maxDF,
  numPartitions=125,
  properties=connectionProps
)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the kind answer, I run it and at least printed the rdd number 125... but when I try to make the new df :
`df_1 = df.select(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4',  'col4', 'col5', 'col6']).show()` 

I got a huge error :
`Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:46449)` do you have any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: Just in case I am using `import findspark` and then `findspark.init('/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7')`

Comment: no problem ... could be a separate issue ... are you able to ping that server? how many nodes does your cluster have? might be a bad network connection or RAM running out on that server

Comment: yes I am able to ping the server, the instance I am using for the EC2 is the (r5d.xlarge 4 vCPUs 32 GiB)  and to be hones I did not create any cluster, I just create the instance and start to try to make it work with jupyter notebook......

Comment: ok since nothing is getting distributed in ```local``` mode try setting the ```numPartitions = 8``` ... you should also perform some kind of ```dataframe``` ```.filter()``` to limit the ```25GB``` sized object